Are line elements vectors or covectors?
In continuum mechanics literature I regularly read statements such that the deformation gradient $\mathbf{F}$ of the flow map $\boldsymbol\varphi$ transforms line elements $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{X}$ from the domain of $\boldsymbol\varphi$ to its range.
I always find the notation confusing because in other literature, e.g. global analysis or differential geometry books, $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{X}$ would be a 1-form on the domain, and would not transform with $\mathbf{F}$ directly, but rather with its inverse transpose.
I was surprised to read in Chadwicks Continuum Mechanics, a book and author for which I have great respect, that the same notation or nomenclature was used. Especially since Chadwick uses the wedge product in his book. I have to admit to being not very well versed in differential forms above 1-forms.
Is his text contradictory around Chapter 3, Figure 2? In case you don't have it (get it!) he states the following:
The two curves $C_t$ and $D_t$ on the right intersect at $x$ in the current configuration. The curves are images of $C_r$ and $D_r$ on the left, which intersect at $X$. Elementary arcs of $C_r$ and $D_r$ given by $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{Y}$, respectively are carried into the elementary arcs $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{y}$ on the right.
$\varphi$" />
Clearly, the elementary arcs are just (contravariant) tangent vectors to the curves. They certainly transform as vectors. Now he does the following step:
Figure 3 shows a material surface $S_t$ on the right in the current configuration, which is the image of $S_r$ on the left under $\boldsymbol\varphi$. An area element $\mathrm{d}A$ at the point $X$ on $S_r$, defined by the vectors $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{Y}$ each tangent to $S_r$, is mapped into $\mathrm{d}a$ at $x=\boldsymbol\varphi(X)$ in $S_t$ on the right defined by the vectors $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{y}$ into which $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{Y}$ are carried. Thus $\mathbf{N}\mathrm{d}A = \mathrm{d}\mathbf{X} \wedge \mathrm{d}\mathbf{Y}$ and $\mathbf{n}\mathrm{d}a = \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x} \wedge \mathrm{d}\mathbf{y}$, for unit normal vectors $\mathbf{N}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ at $X$ and $x$ respectively. The connection between these directed areas, ..., is
$$\mathbf{n}\mathrm{d}a = (\mathbf{F}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{X}) \wedge (\mathbf{F}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{Y}) = \mathbf{F}^* (\mathrm{d}\mathbf{X} \wedge \mathrm{d}\mathbf{Y}) = (\det\mathbf{F}) \mathbf{F}^{-\top} \mathbf{N}\mathrm{d}A 
$$

His definitions are based on the adjugate as given here :

I am confused about the use of line elements that are really vectors, in a wedge product representing a directed area, which is clearly a 2-form. Is there a way to write this more consistently with wedge products between 1-forms? Or is this a calculation that only applies for a Euclidean coordinate system?

I can’t go through this now, but Marsden and Hughes have a book on continuum mechanics. Marsden is very clear in his writing and doesn’t mix up differential geometric objects (and he’s pretty explicit in relating various terminologies).

yes Prop 2.14 is relevant I think. But perhaps dX is consered like a covariant basis for 1-forms and then does transform as Chadwick shows.

Actually Box 2.1 there basically agrees with Chadwick, if dX is the dual basis
